# add event on month week and day button of full calender 2.0.3

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar v2.0.3 of jquery. I want to add some function on month, week and day button. For that I used on() method like -

```
$(".fc-agendaWeek-button").on( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); 
});
```

But this is not working. I don't know why.
Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because fullCalendar hasn't been loaded at that point yet. Use event delegation instead:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
}).on('click', '.fc-agendaWeek-button', function() {
    alert('Week button clicked');
});
```

[See also this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0gkz8e3/)